# read denied from Firebase for authenticated user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Hi everyone I´m new into this and I´ve been having a problem on simulating security rules. It appears that even with an authenticated uid I cannot access to read "Flashcards" (Line 4: read denied) ; neither with an admin uid, write on "Flashcards" (Line 5). Any idea of what might be happening?

Thanks!

These are my rules:

```
{
   "rules": {
     "Flashcards": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').hasChild('auth.uid')",
        ".write": "root.child('admins').hasChild('auth.uid')"
         },
     "users": {
      "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
              } 
      }
}
}
```

And this is an example of my database:

```
{
  "Flashcards": {
    "Deck A": {
      "1": [
        {
            "Question": "Question A",
            "Answer": "Answer A"
        },
        {
            "Question": "Question B",
            "Answer": "Answer B"
        },
        {
            "Question": "Question C",
            "Answer": "Answer C"
        }
        ],
        "2": [
            {
                "Question": "Question A",
                "Answer": "Answer A"
            },
            {
                "Question": "Question B",
                "Answer": "Answer B"
            },
            {
                "Question": "Question C",
                "Answer": "Answer C"
            }
            ]
    }
    },
  "admins": {
    "uid": {
        "name" : "John"
        }
  },
  "users": {
    "uid" : {
        "Actividad" : "Otro"
      },
      "uid" : {
        "Actividad" : "Otro"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is failing.

Comment: I've specified the line of code that is failing, idk if that is what you meant.

Comment: Your questions contains the JSON that you're trying to read, and the rules that control access to that JSON. What is missing is the (Swift, Java, JavaScript or something like that) code that is trying to read the JSON.

Comment: I see. Mmm... I am doing this on the rule simulator of real-time DB on firebase.  Can I get what you're asking in the simulation?

Comment: In that case a screenshot of the simulator is also fine. We simply need to be able to see what you're doing.

Comment: Great. I'll post it tomorrow morning. I don't have my computer rn. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening that you are using 'auth.uid' as a string, and not as predefined variable.
So read rule should be like this (without single quotes):

```
    ".read": "root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
```

Comment: Well spotted! I completely missed that.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! It worked just fine to read for aut users and write for admins.